# Css about floated div's parent

Tags: html, css

I've the web page like the below layout.
The content of css file  is following.

```
#green{
border:20px solid #3D3;
float:left;
display:block;
}
#orange{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:10px solid orange;
float:left;
}

.child{
 border:10px solid black;
 display:inline-block;
 margin:0px;
}
.parent{
  border:10px solid #f00;
  display:table;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

  .clear{
   clear:both;
  }
```

The html content is following.

```
 <div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   <div id='green'> </div>
   <div id="orange"></div>
   <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I've gotten the rendering result as following.

[image]

why do I have white gap in the layout?
I've not added any white color gap in the div tag.
Please help me.
Thanks.

Comment: http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is happened because you set parent display property to table and child display property to inline-block . just remove  **display:inline-block;** property of your **div.child** ,it works fine.I'm added the snippet below.

```css
#green{
border:20px solid #3D3;
float:left;
display:block;
}
#orange{
width:100px;
height:100px;
border:10px solid orange;
float:left;
}

.child{
 border:10px solid black;
 /*display:inline-block;*/
 margin:0px;
}
.parent{
  border:10px solid #f00;
  display:table;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  }

  .clear{
   clear:both;
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
   <div id='green'> </div>
   <div id="orange"></div>
   <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between the div tag with inline-block and one without inline-block?  Does the tag with inline-block has the bottom gap?

Answer (score 0):

Fighting the Space Between Inline Block Elements ,The reason you get the spaces is because, well, you have spaces between the elements (a line break and a few tabs counts as a space, just to be clear). Minimized HTML will solve this problem, you can simply fix this `font-size:0` property ,
check the reference site https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

```
.parent {
  font-size:0;
}
```

see the attached snippet

```css
#green {
 border: 20px solid #3D3;
 float: left;
 display: block;
}
#orange {
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 border: 10px solid orange;
 float: left;
}
.child {
 border: 10px solid black;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0px;
}
.parent {
 border: 10px solid #f00;
 display: table;
 padding: 0px;
 margin: 0px;
    font-size:0;
}
.clear {
 clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div id='green'> </div>
    <div id="orange"></div>
    <div class="clear"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @andrew Li did you check this answer ? you can find why you having a whitespace